# apache spark graphx - create VertexRDD from sql table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-graphx

I have table which I'm loading to Dataframe in Spark, it has the following schema:

```
verticesDf.printSchema

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- target: string (nullable = true)
 |-- batch_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- x: double (nullable = true)
 |-- y: double (nullable = true)
 |-- z: double (nullable = true)
 |-- size: double (nullable = true)
```

How can I transform it to VertexRDD so later I can build a Graph with it?

I was trying the following:

```
case class SRow( target:String, batch_id:Double, x:Double, y:Double, z:Double, size:Double)
val sourceDS: Dataset[(VertexId, SRow)] = verticesDf.as[(VertexId, SRow)]
val vertVX=VertexRDD(sourceDS)
```

but this and many others doesn't give result - I'm always getting some type mismatch. What is the proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least, to create a graph you need two RDDs. One of type `RDD[(VertexId, VD)]` that contains the vertices. A `VertexId` is nothing more than a `Long` and `VD` can be anything, your `Srow` class for instance. The other RDD is of type `RDD[Edge[ED]]`, where `ED` similarly to `VD` can be anything.

Here you talk about the creation of the vextex RDD. You are trying to convert your dataframe to a dataset of type `Dataset[(VertexId, SRow)]`. It does not work for two reasons. `id` is an integer and not a long, and the structure is wrong. Your dataframe contains more than two columns.

Here is how to do it:

```
val vertices = verticesDf
    .select(
       // we transform the id to a long
       'id cast "long",
       // we create a struct with the other columns that will be turned into a Srow
       struct(verticesDf.columns.tail.map(col) : _*))
    .as[(Long, SRow)]

// we also need edges, let's create a dummy RDD
val edges = sc.parallelize(Seq(Edge(1L, 2L, "test")))

// And voila
val graph: Graph[SRow,String] = Graph(vertices.rdd, edges)
```

Note on the last line that a graph is created from RDDs, not datasets so we need to make the transformation for the vertices.

Comment: thank you for answering. after posting question I was able to get to the cast of integer to long as well, however mapping you provided is something awesome